# Cocoa OSX app hangs on dispatch_async

Tags: multithreading, macos, cocoa, grand-central-dispatch

My app fires off a thread specifically for checking the status of a process. It fires every 5-10 seconds:

```
if(!monitorTask){
        MYLog(100,@"Monitor task is dead");
        return;
}
dispatch_async(monitorTask,^{ // fuckup here
        MYLog(150,@"...Checking iTunes");
```

However it also seems to hang there every so often:

[image]

Any clues how to fix/catch this? The app is beachballing but "running" in Xcode just fine - stuck on this instruction:

[image]

Comment: What is `monitorTask`? Please provide its initializing code.
`dispatch_async`-function schedules block for performing. You need to pass `dispatch_queue_t` as the first argument.

Comment: Yes, it's created properly. It looks like it's only hanging if it is running via Xcode

Comment: Please show `monitorTask` init code.

Comment: if(!monitorTask)monitorTask=dispatch_queue_create(          "com.map-pin.Dapper.montr",NULL);

Comment: can't see the label in debugger (first picture)

Comment: The monitor task is initialized at app launch - minutes before the code in question runs

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that monitorTask is of type `dispatch_queue_t`?  [See these Apple guides for an example of how to create a serial queue](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW6)

Though I see in your comment that you are creating the queue correctly.

It is also possible that the queue may be deallocated before you can dispatch to it.  You may need to [perform some memory management](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW11) on your queue to ensure that it isn't deallocated before you dispatch.

**Lastly** it is important to note that serial queues are by-and-large used to protect shared resources.  If you are just trying to perform a periodic check on a resource (a task that would never write, and only read), then you are going to be better off using a concurrent queue (you should probably just use one of the [4 given global queues,](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW5)

Or because you are seemingly perpetually checking throughout the lifetime of the application, you could even look into using a [Dispatch Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/GCDWorkQueues/GCDWorkQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH103-SW1), more specifically a Timer Dispatch Source

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be an Xcode debugger problem, because I cannot replicate it while running the app outside of Xcode :-/